# Cant loop over files with spaces in the filename, windows batch file and image magick

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, imagemagick

I'm trying to loop over a bunch of folders, create subfolders then loop on the files, convert them with imagemagick and put them into the new subfolders and rename them. Some files have spaces in their name and cause the error... How can I fix this?

error message :

```
convert: unable to open image 'photo': No such name or directory @error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3489. convert: no decode delegate for this image format '' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/554.**
```

The Folder Structure looks like this...
The Folder Structure looks like this...

```
batch_file.bat
folder_a
...photo 1.jpg
...photo1.jpg
folder_b
...photo 1.jpg
...photo2.png
```

I want it to end up like this

```
batch_file.bat
folder_a
...300
......1.webp
......1.jpg
......2.webp
......2.jpg
...600
......1.webp
......1.jpg
......2.webp
......2.jpg
...photo 1.jpg
...photoC.jpg
folder_b
...300
......1.webp
......1.jpg
......2.webp
......2.jpg
...600
......1.webp
......1.png
......2.webp
......2.png
...photo 1.jpg
...photoA.png
```

If possible I'd like to rename the files to 1.jpg, 1.webp, 2.jpg, 2.webp etc...

The batch File looks like this...

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
%~d1
CD "%~p1"
SET FOLDERS=300 600
FOR /D %%r IN (*) DO (
    CD %%r
    ECHO In Folder: %%r
    FOR %%f IN (%FOLDERS%) DO (
        MD %%f
        ECHO In Folder: %%f
        PAUSE
        FOR %%a IN (*.jpg, *.png) DO (
            convert %%a -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -strip -quality 85 -interlace JPEG -colorspace RGB -resize %%f %%f\%%a   
            ECHO Converting File: %%a
            mogrify -format webp %%f\%%a
            PAUSE
        )
    )
    CD ..
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To handle filenames with spaces, quote them. For example your command

```
convert %%a -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -strip -quality 85 -interlace JPEG -colorspace RGB -resize %%f %%f\%%a
```

should change to

```
convert "%%a" -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -strip -quality 85 -interlace JPEG -colorspace RGB -resize "%%f" "%%f\%%a"
```

same with the `mogrify` command:

```
mogrify -format webp "%%f\%%a"
```

The quotes doesn't do any harm, when there is *no* space, so as best practice get used to always qoute path- or file names.

Comment: If possible I'd like to rename the files to 1.jpg, 1.webp, 2.jpg, 2.webp etc How would I go about doing this? @Stephan

Comment: Easy: implement a counter `set counter=0`. Then inside the `for` loop increment it with `set /a counter+=1` and use `!counter!` to build the new filename (use `%%~xa` to get the original file's extension). If you have difficulties, please ask a new question; chamaeleon questions aren't received well here.

Comment: That worked too thanks, Okay. Thanks for the heads up :).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Stephan and his answer's I've got the spaces and the rename working. Heres the result.

```
@echo off
%~d1
CD "%~p1"
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET FOLDERS=300 600

FOR /D %%r IN (*) DO (
    CD %%r
    ECHO In Folder: %%r
    ECHO Checking for pngs
    FOR %%a IN (*.png) DO (
        ECHO Converting %%a to .jpg
        mogrify -format jpg "%%a"
    )
    FOR %%f IN (%FOLDERS%) DO (
        MD %%f
        ECHO In Folder: %%r\%%f
        SET counter=0
        FOR %%a IN (*.jpg) DO (
            SET /a counter+=1
            ECHO Optimizing File: %%a : Into !counter!%%~xa
            convert "%%a" -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -strip -quality 85 -interlace JPEG -colorspace RGB -resize "%%f" "%%f\!counter!%%~xa"
            ECHO Converting Optimized File: !counter!%%~xa into .webp
            mogrify -format webp "%%f\!counter!%%~xa"
        )
    )
    CD ..
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert images to webp format using ffmpeg.exe.
The ffmpeg.exe file must be placed in the folder of this script.

```
@echo off
echo Attention!
echo When entering paths, a backslash '\' at the end of the path is not allowed!
echo For example: C:\Pictures is correct, but C:\Pictures\ is not.
echo Make sure there are no duplicate file names in folders.
echo For example, two files: Photo1.jpg and Photo1.png located in the same folder will be perceived as identical files
echo and will be prompted to overwrite the existing file. As a result, one of them will not be recorded.
echo If these files are in different folders, then this is not a problem.
set target=""
set /p target="Enter the path to the source folder: "
set outpath=""
set /p outpath="Enter the path to the folder with the new .webp files: "
if "%target%"=="""" (
    echo The path to the folder with source files has not been entered. Execution will be aborted.
) else if "%outpath%"=="""" (
    echo The path to the folder with the new .webp files has not been entered. Execution will be aborted.
) else (
    echo %target%
    for /r "%target%" %%i in (*.jpg *.jpeg *.gif *.png *.bmp) do (
    mkdir "%outpath%%%~pi"
    ffmpeg -i "%%i" -vcodec libwebp "%outpath%%%~pi\%%~ni.webp"
    )
) 
pause
```